# How to express $e^{yS^2}(f(x))$ in closed form where $\frac{d}{dx}=S$

Tags: functions, operator-theory, taylor-expansion

$$ f(x)+\frac{y.f'(x)}{1!}+\frac{y^2 f^{''}(x)}{2!}+\cdots=e^{yS}(f(x))=f(x+y) \text{ where }\frac{d}{dx}=S$$ is a operator

$$ f(x)+\frac{y.f''(x)}{1!}+\frac{y^2 f^{(4)}(x)}{2!}+\cdots=e^{yS^2}(f(x))=?$$ how can it be expressed  as f(x)?

The most nearly expression I had:

$$ f(x)+\frac{y.f''(x)}{2!}+\frac{y^2 f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2} (e^{\sqrt{y}S}(f(x))+e^{-\sqrt{y}S}(f(x)))=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+\sqrt{y})+f(x-\sqrt{y}))$$

Is there any way to express $e^{yS^2}(f(x))$ as closed form of $f(x)$?

Thanks for answers

EDIT: I thought fourier transform  may help to get progress, What I tried:

Fourier transform of $f(x)$ can be written
$$F(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{-2πixt} \mathrm{d}t$$

inverse Fourier transform of $f(x)$ can be written
$$f(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(t)e^{2πixt} \mathrm{d}t$$

Thus

$$f^{(2n)}(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(t) (2πit)^{(2n)}e^{2πixt} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$\frac{y^nf^{(2n)}(x)}{n!}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(t) \frac{y^n(2πit)^{(2n)}}{n!}e^{2πixt} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^nf^{(2n)}(x)}{n!}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(t) (\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^n(2πit)^{(2n)}}{n!})e^{2πixt} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^nf^{(2n)}(x)}{n!}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(t) (\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{((2πit)^2y)^{(n)}}{n!})e^{2πixt} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^nf^{(2n)}(x)}{n!}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(t) e^{(2πit)^2y} e^{2πixt} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^nf^{(2n)}(x)}{n!}=e^{yS^2}(f(x))= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(t) e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πixt}  \mathrm{d}t$$

$$e^{yS^2}(f(x))= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u)e^{-2πiut}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πixt} \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}t$$

$$e^{yS^2}(f(x))= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2πiut}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πixt}  \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}u$$

Now Need to find

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2πiut}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πixt}  \mathrm{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πi(x-u)t}  \mathrm{d}t $$

EDIT:(after @Winther comment)

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πi(x-u)t}  \mathrm{d}t =e^{4π^2y\alpha^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-4π^2y(t-\alpha)^2}  \mathrm{d}t$$

Where  $$2\alpha.(-4\pi^2y)=2\pi i(x-u)$$

$$\alpha=\frac{-i(x-u)}{4\pi y}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πi(x-u)t}  \mathrm{d}t =e^{\frac{-(x-u)^2}{4y}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-4π^2y(t-\alpha)^2}  \mathrm{d}t$$

$$z=t-\alpha$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πi(x-u)t}  \mathrm{d}t =e^{\frac{-(x-u)^2}{4y}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{-4π^2yz^2}  \mathrm{d}z=\frac{e^{\frac{-(x-u)^2}{4y}}}{2\sqrt{\pi y}}$$

$$e^{yS^2}(f(x))= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2πiut}  e^{-4π^2yt^2+2πixt}  \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}u=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u) \frac{e^{\frac{-(x-u)^2}{4y}}}{2\sqrt{\pi y}} \mathrm{d}u$$

Finally the result can be written as

$$e^{yS^2}(f(x))=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi y}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u) e^{\frac{-(x-u)^2}{4y}} \mathrm{d}u$$

Please check my result if I made a mistake during calculations.
Thanks for comments and advice.

Comment: I highly doubt it, but it seems hard to prove it. It's fairly easy to show that a linear-in-$f$ formula (which do not need $f',f'',\ldots$ to be expressed) cannot exist as $e^{yS^2}f = \sum a_n(y) f(x+b_n(y))$ implies $e^{yS^2} = \sum a_n(y) e^{b_n(y) S}$ which is not true in general.

Comment: @Winther  Could you please check my last edit? I believe it can help to prove or disprove that a linear in f-formula exists or not. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can try to complete the square (exponent $=(-y(t-C)^2 + yC^2)$) and use $\int e^{-at^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi/a}$. This would give you something like (note $C$ is complex, but we do it Physics style and just threat it as real) $e^{yS^2}f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{y}}\int e^{-\frac{y\pi^2(x-x')^2}{y^2}}f(x') dx'$

Comment: btw equation above is the equation for solutions of the Heat Equation and $e^{\ldots}$ is called the [Heat Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel) (which is known to have the representation $e^{yS^2}$ as is commented on in the link I gave above)

Comment: @Winther I updated as you commented. Is it correct what I got? It seems The form is an integral transform of that operator but no any relation for a linear f formula. Maybe I need to do some more transforms in last integral to get my aim. Thanks for advice

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  $$ f(x)+\frac{y.f''(x)}{2!}+\frac{y^2 f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2} (e^{\sqrt{y}S}(f(x))+e^{-\sqrt{y}S}(f(x)))=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+\sqrt{y})+f(x-\sqrt{y}))$$  but I am looking for a closed form of $ f(x)+\frac{y.f''(x)}{1!}+\frac{y^2 f^{(4)}(x)}{2!}+\cdots$ if we can express it as $\sum a_n(y)f(x+b_n(y))$ or not

Comment: @Mathlover Yes, your final result is correct. As a test of your final expression you can try to apply it to some simple functions $1 \to I = 1$, $x \to I = x$, $x^2 \to I = x^2 + 2y$ (all for which your formula give the correct result)

Comment: @Winther Thanks a lot for comments. The final expression is very beautiful. I will focus on some examples to confirm .It can be used as a nice tool.

Comment: No problems. btw if you want a physical interpretation of your transform: if $f(x) = T(x,0)$ is a temperature distibution at $t=0$ then $e^{yS^2}f(x) = T(x, y)$ is the temperature distribution at time $t=y$ since $T(x,y)$ satisfy the heat equation $\frac{\partial T(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 T(x,y)}{\partial x^2}$ with initial condition $T(x,0) = f(x)$.